# Magento 2 : Readiness Check Fail

Tags: magento2, admin, upgrade, component

I have site which is running on **Magento 2.1.7 CE**.

When I tried to upgrade site from admin using

```
System -> Tools -> Web Setup Wizard
```

it stop on

```
Step 2: Readiness Check
```

and showing error in **Check Component Dependency** : like screen-sort.

[image]

So, I search for the issue on web and every where I get solution about increase **memory_limit**.

And I change limit in php.ini avilable in magento root folder, And my change increase the memory_limit. See screen-sort.

[image]

After this also get same error. When I check my error.log file it showing something like this.

[image]

Error Log : `PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 484450304) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)`

Can any one help me into this,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share these details with your server team to get them updated. You will need to Match the server configuration that Magento Needs.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `xampp/wamp/lamp` & search for the `php.ini` file & change there in `memory_limit` & save the file & `restart your server` you will get the solution for your question.

It seems like your master value is 2048M & local value is 768M

For server simply just search for or try to put a file with name `.user.ini` in your `public_html` folder and put this code there

```
memory_limit = 2G
```

than try to run this command

```
php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Thank You!

Comment: I am working on live site, means the site working on web server.

Comment: I try to set this .user.ini still same error occured.

Comment: @Dhiren Vasoya both the memory_limit are showing same?

Comment: yes, now both memory_limit show 2048M, but problem still exist.

Comment: look now I have updated my answer try that command to your server.

Comment: I try that command, still same problem.

Comment: delete all the files present in the pub folder except htaccess & than run this command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: still the same issue, can you tell me why it take more memory_limit?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66324/discussion-between-abhishek-tripathi-and-dhiren-vasoya).

Comment: Memory limit: 8GB, still getting same error, may i know how to solve?

Comment: It can be due to not full filling some of the component dependency.just look for the component are set, Php version, php.ini is set as per requirement & the extensions required are available there on your server. If still facing something then put a detailed question at MSE

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by doing this.

1. I increased memory_limit in **.user.ini** file available in **Magento** root directory.
2. Then removed **Require dev tag** from `composer.json` available in **Magento** root directory.